# Creating a custom content type in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

i tried to create a **custom content type** in drupal but unnecessary features like **Title**, **Menu settings**, and **Revision Information**, **URL aliases** come with it which i don't really want ..coz it doesn't mean anything to the user..
how can i hide all those things, just preserving the fields(say only 3 fields from CCK) that i want only for this custom content type??
thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can automatically generate titles using the [auto_nodetitle](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module, which also enables you to remove the title field from the node submission form.

As others have mentioned above, most of the other form elements don't appear to non-admin users anyway.

Answer (score 2):

With auto_nodetitle module, you can hide it, not remove it. Then, simply assign a title like "your-content-type-nid", so it will be different for each node (nid will be different).
That would be a better title than an empty one.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do a combination of things to do what you want. One of those is to add the module auto_nodetitle suggested by others. You can hide the "Body" by removing the "Body field label" from the edit screen for your custom content type. Lastly is that you will have to do the right settings for your CCK fields.

If you have CCK fields you want them to be able to edit and others you do not want them to edit, you will need to enable the Content Permissions module in the CCK section of the modules admin page. Once you've done that, you can go to the role permissions page and set what roles have access to which fields. While permissions can potentially hide CCK fields from the user, you can also control what fields are in the teaser, node, and RSS views via the "Display fields" section of your content type editing screens.

Answer (score 1):

Menu settings, revision info and URL alias type info is admin stuff. If you create a new user that doesn't have admin permissions, I'm pretty sure they won't see it.

Comment: yeah, but can i hide the title field? i just want a upload and a body field only in a page..how can i do that?

Comment: As has already been said, you can't really hide the title field, but I presume your theme isn't displaying it so the users soon learn not to bother filling it in ;-)

Comment: Exactly. Nodes in drupal have titles, but simply don't show them on the page and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Can try some thing like below using hook_form_alter.

function my_module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

```
if($form_id='company_node_form'){
    $form['menu']['#prefix'] ='<div style="display:none">';
    $form['menu']['#suffix'] ='</div>';
    $form['revision_information']['#prefix'] ='<div style="display:none">';
    $form['revision_information']['#suffix'] ='</div>';
    $form['author']['#prefix'] ='<div style="display:none">';
    $form['author']['#suffix'] ='</div>';
    $form['options']['#prefix'] ='<div style="display:none">';
    $form['options']['#suffix'] ='</div>';
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the NodeFormCols module.  It does several handy things, among them is to add a Manage Form button which allows you to hide most fields in an input form.